# Sprouting turtles in NetLogo based on patch value

Tags: netlogo

I have loaded an ASCII file in NetLogo with values (ranging from 0 - 4.6) that represent the mean number (of a Poisson process) of turtles inhabiting the patch.  I'd like to setup the model to sprout turtles on each patch using random-poisson with the mean value derived from the ASCII file.  I know how to `ask n-of patches` to sprout a certain number of turtles but I don't know how to ask the sprout command to act on all patches.  Any help would be great!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it right, Do you need each patch to sprout a specific number of turtles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is asking all patches you can use following:

```
to setup 
  clear-all
  resize-world 0 10 0 10
  set-patch-size 40
  let ASCII-file-Values   n-values 121 [ random-poisson mean n-values 121[random-float 4.6]]
  let patches_list sort patches


  let i 0 
  foreach patches_list [
    ask ? [

      sprout item i ASCII-file-Values  
      set plabel count turtles-here
    ]
    set i i + 1
  ]

  reset-ticks      
end
```

The only section which answers your question is the `foreach patches_list []` If you need values assigned to the patches to be used later, another way could be adding a varible to each patch and set this value in the foreach loop, then you can `ask patches [ sprout my-value]`

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to do without the loop counter (`let i ... set i ...`) by iterating over both lists at once, like this: `(foreach patches-list ascii-file-values [ ask ?1 [ set plabel ?2 ] ])`