# NetLogo: Calculate turtles' offsprings on patches (by sprout function?)

Tags: netlogo

On my NetLogo world surface, I would like to count the number of turtles on pink patches. Next, I want to include the reproduction process. More specifically **I want to multiply number of turtles on these patches by number of offspring per turtle (3) and thus create new turtles.** The offspring should have the quality of their parents.

In steps: 
1. create 100 turtles on pink patches (parents)
2. identify number of turtles per pink patch (I want to incorporate this model into bigger one) and multiply it by 3 -> 100 parents have 300 offspring
3. let parents die, keep only offspring
4. resulting number of turtle per pink patch: 300

It seems the use of `sprout` could be adequate to produce turtles on each pink patch. However I don't understand how can I include this offspring creation? I know that I can count number of turtles per patch by

> show [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = pink]

but how to include this information in my new turtles (offspring) creation? and how to "copy" quality of their parents? (being red?)

I tried to incorporate answer published here but without success: [Sprouting turtles in NetLogo based on patch value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101942/sprouting-turtles-in-netlogo-based-on-patch-value)

Thank you a lot, here is my code:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

; create diverse landscape
to setup-patches
  ask n-of 5 patches [ set pcolor pink ]
end

; create turtles on pink patches

to setup-turtles 
  ask patches with [pcolor = pink] [sprout 100 [ set color red ]]   
  ; ask patches with [pcolor = pink] [count turtles-here]
  ; show [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = pink]        ; calculate number of turtles on every pink patch
  let patch-list [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = pink] 
  let i 0
  foreach patch-list [
    ask ? [
      sprout item i patch-list
      set plabel count turtles-here
    ]
    set i i + 1
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primitive you are looking for is [`hatch`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#hatch). If you `ask` a parent to `hatch` an offspring, it automatically copies all the parent's attributes in the offspring:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask n-of 5 patches [ set pcolor pink ]

  ; create 100 parent turtles on pink patches
  ask patches with [ pcolor = pink ] [ sprout 100 ]

  ; show that each pink patch has 100 turtles on it (the parents)
  show [ count turtles-here ] of patches with [ pcolor = pink ]

  ; ask each parent to hatch 3 offsprings and then die
  ask turtles [
    hatch 3
    die
  ]

  ; show that each pink patch now has 300 turtles on it (the offsprings)
  show [ count turtles-here ] of patches with [ pcolor = pink ]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, incorporating

> sprout count turtles-here

into my simple formula:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of 5 patches [ set pcolor pink ]
end

to setup-turtles 
  ; create parents
  ask patches with [pcolor = pink] [sprout 100 [ set color red ]]  
  ; create offsprings (*3) and let parents die (- count turtles-here)
  ask patches with [pcolor = pink] 
    [sprout count turtles-here * 3 - count turtles-here [ set color red ]]
  ; show [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = pink] 
  ask patches with [pcolor = pink] [set plabel count turtles-here]  
end
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements from your question. You said you wanted to create 100 parent turtles on each pink patch, have those create 300 offspring on each patch, and then kill the 100 parents. What your code does is create 100 turtles on each pink patch, and then create 200 more on each patch. That's somewhat different.

Comment: Thank you @NicolasPayette ! :) yeah, your solution is much better.