# Limiting the number of turtles spawned in a circle

Tags: visualization, netlogo

A NetLogo newbie here. I am trying to limit the number of turtles that get spawned in a circle, so that the turtles do not overlay each other. So far I have tried the approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101942/sprouting-turtles-in-netlogo-based-on-patch-value), where there is a list of all patches and turtles get spawned per patch, but it was still too many turtles for my circle. Out of curiousity I tried to spawn only when `turtle number mod PRIME NUMBER` was `0`, but there weren't just two turtles that spawned, there were more! And in my case the patches themselves don't really matter, as my model is not really spatial. The `resize-world` and `set-patch-size`are there for size consistency, as without them the visualization turns out to be quite small and I haven't figured out how to reset it back yet.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
breed [people person]

to setup
  clear-all
  make-people
end

to make-people
  resize-world 0 30 0 30
  set-patch-size 20
  ask patches
  [
    ask people
    [
      set shape "circle"
    ]
    sprout-people (1)
    layout-circle people 15
  ]
end
```

Here is what it produces:

[image: What the visualisation looks like so far]

How do I get the turtles spaced out well instead of being squished together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that each patch is creating one person (`sprout`) which then get placed into the circle. There are three different commands for creating turtle agents, `sprout` is where a patch creates the turtle, usually used to control the location of new turtles. Since space is not meaningful for you, a better approach is to use the `create` command and simply specify how many you want, increasing or decreasing the number until the spacing meets your needs. Try this, and change the 50 until you get what you want.

```
to make-people
  create-people 50
  [ set shape "circle"
  ]
  layout-circle people 15
end
```

For the size of the world - you can go to the interface and use the settings drop down box to set the dimensions you want.